# Getting href value with jquery ( invalid characters? )

Tags: jquery, html

I have a link in HTML thats structured like:

`<a href="#!/example/1234" class="details">details</a>`

When I target this a tag with `$("a.details").attr('href')` or `$("a.details")[0].href` both return only the `#` portion of the href and nothing past it.

I tried searching for what is valid and invalid characters for a href attribute in an `'<a>'` tag and didn't turn up anything really useful. I know that `#` denotes it being an anchor tag but why would this block it from jquery reading the value?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: what your `a` tag exactly having?? show us the `HTML`

Comment: sorry just forgot to have the code wrapping around the html

Comment: For jQuery 1.6 and above, you should use `prop()` in place of `attr()`.  If your last comment is telling us that you solved your problem, then please post it as an answer below and accept your own answer.

Comment: Might as well get used to using `prop()`.  See accepted answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Comment: Yeah this is the first time I have seen prop so if nothing else I appreciate pointing this out!

Answer (score 3):

Works fine for me here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Hz9uX/

Are you putting quotation marks around your `a.details`?

`$('a.details').attr('href')`

Comment: yeah sorry I have the selector formatted correctly $('a.details').attr('href'). Still giving me just getting #. When the href was just href="1234" i was able to get number just fine but once the whole #!/product/1234 was added it stopped reading it properly.

Comment: Did you try my fiddle? What appears in the alert? Also, what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Yeah I do see it working in your example. I just made sure it wasn't an issue of timing since some of this stuff is dynamically added but even the timeout happening well after the fact logs out a '#' :(

Comment: It probably either has something to do with you dynamically adding it after it checks the anchor tag or you're using an old version of jQuery.  I'd put my money on the former. Without more code, we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try [(demo)](http://jsfiddle.net/JWEE9/)

```
$('a').attr('href');
```

Comment: There's no reason why he can't use `a.details` and your code has an extra `)` which makes it syntactically incorrect.

Comment: @Switz ohh That's a typo .Thanks